# LetsEncrypt without DNS verification?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, google-cloud-platform, lets-encrypt, bitnami

I have a Bitnami Wordpress site using cPanel. The site is using cPanel's SSL. I want to migrate to another server without cPanel.

I've done the necessary files migration and want to use Let'sEncrypt for the new server. This is the command line `sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool`

However, it requires DNS validation to proceed with the SSL setup. I feel jittery to point the DNS to the new server without doing a thorough checking first.

Is there a way to set up Let's Encrypt without DNS validation first?

I don't know if this question belongs here, if is inappropriate can you kindly direct me to the right SE community? Thanks.

Comment: For Let's Encrypt : (1) Apart from DNS (known as DNS-01 challenge), you can use web page type validation in web server (HTTP-01 challenge).  (2) Apart from certbot, you can use a variety of ACME clients to do the job (I have used Bash, C, PHP, Python, etc. and all are fine) .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Let's Encrypt `certbot` tool supports manual certificate generation. This tool will ask you to manually create TXT records at your DNS server. This command can be run at your web server or any system that has `certbot` installed.

Example command:

```
sudo ./certbot -d example.com -d www.example.com --manual --preferred-challenges dns certonly
```

https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#manual